# Translational Ward Identity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, ward-identity

The Ward identity corresponding to energy-momentum conservation (translational invariance) is (see for instance [Di Francesco](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387947853) Eq.(4.63) )

$$\partial_\mu \langle T^\mu_\nu X \rangle = - \sum_i \delta(x-x_i) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i^\nu} \langle X \rangle $$

where $X = \Phi_1 (x_1) ... \Phi_n(x_n)$. I want to stress that, if I am not mistaken, this is for any kind of fields $\Phi$, not only scalars (all fields are "scalars" with respect to translations, so what else could you write on the RHS, apart from the derivative?).

So far so good. Now look at Eq.(6.33) in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9307010.pdf), or Eq. (3.122) in [this other paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.09105.pdf). In the first one for instance they have $X = T^{\rho \sigma} ( y) T^{\alpha \beta} (z)$, and new terms appear in the RHS. They have:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} \langle T^\mu_\nu(x) T^\rho_\sigma (y) T^\alpha_\beta(z) \rangle = \\
 \partial_\nu \delta(x-y) \langle T^{\rho}_\sigma(y) T^\alpha_\beta(z) \rangle  + \partial_\nu \delta(x-z) \langle T^{\rho}_\sigma (y) T^{\alpha}_\beta (z)\rangle\\
 + \partial_\rho \delta(x-y)  \langle T^\sigma_\nu(x) T^\alpha_\beta (z) \rangle  + (\rho \leftrightarrow \sigma) \\
+ \partial_\alpha \delta(x-z)  \langle T^\beta_\nu(x) T^\rho_\sigma (y) \rangle  + (\alpha \leftrightarrow \beta) .
$$

**Questions**

**1) Why the two first terms have a plus sign, while according to Di Francesco it should be a minus?**

**2) Where do the other four terms come from?**

Comment: In the first formula the derivative is acting on $X$. In the second formula the derivative acts on the Dirac Delta function.

Comment: @Prahar do you think the sign comes from integrating by parts? It is a strange way of writing the identity though... And the other terms?